# PySpark Nested Dataframe

Tags: python, json, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I need some Python Pyspark help. I have a source object that looks like:
Edit: Both lists are numpy arrays of numpy data types

```
obj = [("thing1", ([1,2,3], [0.1,0.2,0.3]),
       ("thing2", ([1,2,3], [0.1,0.2,0.3]),
       ("thing3", ([1,2,3], [0.1,0.2,0.3]),
       ("thing4", ([1,2,3], [0.1,0.2,0.3]),
       ...]
```

Is there a way to create spark dataframe so it looks like this. Where the object in "column2" is essentially another dataframe of two columns labeled "label1" and "label2":

```
"column1" | "column2"
---------------------
"thing1"  | [{"label1": 1, "label2": 0.1}, {"label1": 2, "label2": 0.2}, {"label1": 3, "label2": 0.3}]
"thing2"  | [{"label1": 1, "label2": 0.1}, {"label1": 2, "label2": 0.2}}]
...
```

My end goal is to produce a JSON object that looks like this. I need the columns and labels:

```
{{"column1":"thing1", 
  "column2":[{"1abel1":1, "label2":0.1},{"1abel1":2, "label2":0.2},{"1abel1":3, "label2":0.3},
 {"column1":"thing2", 
  "column2":[{"1abel1":1, "label2":0.1},{"1abel1":2, "label2":0.2},{"1abel1":3, "label2":0.3},
 {"column1":"thing3", 
  "column2":[{"1abel1":1, "label2":0.1},{"1abel1":2, "label2":0.2},{"1abel1":3, "label2":0.3},
 ...}
```

If this is possible to do relatively fast for about 1 million records, that would be great too

Comment: Hello! Welcome to StackOverflow! Have you thought about using UDFs to solve this problem?

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the welcome! Yes, I've created several functions to help me but I wanted to see if doing this via dataframe-specific functions would make things faster. I'm using multiprocessing also but it's still so slow.

Comment: For the creation of the dictionary I don't know of a built-in solution outside UDF. But you could always leverage 'explode' and 'collect_list' if you haven't already and limit the udf to the creation of the dict only.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following non-udf based approaches:

#### Approach 1

You may try using [`transform`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.transform.html) to achieve this given that you'll always expect the same amount of label 1 and label 2, otherwise you could always modify the below to perform checks eg

```py
transformed_df = (
    df.withColumn(
        "column3",
        F.transform(
            "column2.label2",
            lambda entry,index: F.struct(
                F.col("column2.label1")[index].alias("label1"),
                F.lit(entry).alias("label2")
            )
        )
    )
)
transformed_df.show(truncate=False)
transformed_df.printSchema()
```

```
+-------+----------------------------+------------------------------+
|column1|column2                     |column3                       |
+-------+----------------------------+------------------------------+
|thing1 |{[1, 2, 3], [0.1, 0.2, 0.3]}|[{1, 0.1}, {2, 0.2}, {3, 0.3}]|
|thing2 |{[1, 2, 3], [0.1, 0.2, 0.3]}|[{1, 0.1}, {2, 0.2}, {3, 0.3}]|
|thing3 |{[1, 2, 3], [0.1, 0.2, 0.3]}|[{1, 0.1}, {2, 0.2}, {3, 0.3}]|
|thing4 |{[1, 2, 3], [0.1, 0.2, 0.3]}|[{1, 0.1}, {2, 0.2}, {3, 0.3}]|
+-------+----------------------------+------------------------------+

root
 |-- column1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- column2: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- label1: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: integer (containsNull = true)
 |    |-- label2: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: float (containsNull = true)
 |-- column3: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = false)
 |    |    |-- label1: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- label2: float (nullable = true)
```

#### Approach 2

You may also map your transformation over the RDD eg

```
from pyspark.sql import Row
transformed_df = df.rdd.map(lambda row: Row(
    column1=row['column1'],
    column2=[ { 
        'label1':entry,
        'label2':row['column2']['label2'][index] 
    } for index,entry in enumerate(row['column2']['label1']) ]
)).toDF(schema="column1 string, column2 array<struct<label1: int, label2: float>>")

transformed_df.show(truncate=False)
transformed_df.printSchema()
```

```
+-------+------------------------------+
|column1|column2                       |
+-------+------------------------------+
|thing1 |[{1, 0.1}, {2, 0.2}, {3, 0.3}]|
|thing2 |[{1, 0.1}, {2, 0.2}, {3, 0.3}]|
|thing3 |[{1, 0.1}, {2, 0.2}, {3, 0.3}]|
|thing4 |[{1, 0.1}, {2, 0.2}, {3, 0.3}]|
+-------+------------------------------+

root
 |-- column1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- column2: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- label1: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- label2: float (nullable = true)
```

#### Setup

The code to reproduce the setup has been included below for debugging purposes.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import types as T

data = [
        ("thing1", ([1,2,3], [0.1,0.2,0.3])),
       ("thing2", ([1,2,3], [0.1,0.2,0.3])),
       ("thing3", ([1,2,3], [0.1,0.2,0.3])),
       ("thing4", ([1,2,3], [0.1,0.2,0.3]))
]

df=spark.createDataFrame(
    data,
    T.StructType([
        T.StructField("column1",T.StringType()),
        T.StructField(
            "column2",
            T.StructType([
                T.StructField("label1",T.ArrayType(T.IntegerType())),
                T.StructField("label2",T.ArrayType(T.FloatType())),
            ])
        )
    ])
)
df.show(truncate=False)
```

```
+-------+----------------------------+
|column1|column2                     |
+-------+----------------------------+
|thing1 |{[1, 2, 3], [0.1, 0.2, 0.3]}|
|thing2 |{[1, 2, 3], [0.1, 0.2, 0.3]}|
|thing3 |{[1, 2, 3], [0.1, 0.2, 0.3]}|
|thing4 |{[1, 2, 3], [0.1, 0.2, 0.3]}|
+-------+----------------------------+
```

Comment: I tried this out but I came across a few problems. This wouldn't output the result JSON I'm looking for. And the data object's arrays are numpy arrays with numpy datatypes which don't work with pyspark.